# Catch Google Maps Error and Render Something Else (or Stop API)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps

I am using Google Maps API. According to the documentation, Google allows me to check **only** authentication failure. I am calling the authfailure function in **componentDidMount**.

```
 window.gm_authFailure = function() {
                alert("Auth failed!");
            };
```

But I need more than that. When I change the API key, first I see that error message(Auth failed), after that app crashes with this automatic message:
*Oops! Something went wrong. This page didn't load Google Maps correctly. See the JavaScript console for technical details.*

I don't want to show this automatic error message and blank gray screen to the user in no case. When API fails in authentication, I need to stop the app or show something else to the user instead of blank gray sreen.